# Guardar la información en un JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Pongamos que tengo este JSON

```
{
"pelicula":[
 { 
  "Titulo":"La vida es bella",
  "Director":"Roberto Benigni"
}
 { 
  "Titulo":"Jurassic park",
  "Director":"Steven Spielberg"
}
    ]
}
```

Y yo quiero añadirle mas películas a este JSON, a través de un formulario, y que esa información se guarde en el fichero JSON. Es posible hacer eso?

Comment: Sí es posible. Inténtalo y si tienes algún error o problema puedes [edit] la pregunta exponiendo el problema concreto y te ayudaremos a resolverlo.

Comment: Si ejecutas en el navegador no puedes guardar directamente en disco (menos en el disco servidor), lo que puedes tener es una opción de "guardar como" pero solo para el cliente. Ahora bien si tu código se ejecuta en el servidor algo como nodejs es otro tema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si se puede, y vamos a tomar de ejemplo el JSON, para ello necesitamos crear un form html donde le pasemos los datos.

para ello crearemos nuestro index

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>JSON || FORM</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <h1>Pelicula</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Titulo de la Pelicula:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Director de la Pelicula</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="director" id="director">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Fecha de Lanzamiento</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="lanzamiento" id="lanzamiento">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="tablaPelicula">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Director</th>
                    <th>Fecha Lanzamiento</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="interfaz.js"></script>
    <script src="logica.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

En donde tendremos 3 campos (Titulo, Director y Fecha de Lanzamiento), si queremos agregar mas, podemos hacerlos después. Una vez creado tu form con tus id, creamos 2 archivos js (al menos así lo maneje).

En el primero tendremos los datos del JSON y en el otro, toda la logica del js.

`interfaz.js`

```js
var peliculaDatos = [];

function agregarDatosPelicula(peliculaTitulo, peliculaDirector, peliculaFechaLanzamiento) {
    
    var NuevaPelicula = {
        title: peliculaTitulo,
        director: peliculaDirector,
        date: peliculaFechaLanzamiento
    };

    console.log(NuevaPelicula); 
    peliculaDatos.push(NuevaPelicula);
}

function obtenerListaPelicula() {
    return peliculaDatos;
}
```

Aqui declaramos un arreglo donde estaremos almacenandos los datos que se vayan agregar a de tu form, mediante la función `agregarDatosPelicula()`. En esta funcion, lo que le dices es debe crear un objeto `NuevaPelicula` donde guadaras tus datos en formato json. Luego todo esto, lo agregas a tu arreglo peliculas datos con el metodo `peliculasDatos.push(NuevaPelicua);`

Una vez comprendido esto, vamos a la logica de todo esto

`logica.js`

```js
document.querySelector('#btnSubmit').addEventListener('click', guardarDatosPeliculas);
imprimirTabla();


function guardarDatosPeliculas() {
    var guardarPeliculaTitulo = document.querySelector('#title').value,
        guardarPeliculaDirector = document.querySelector('#director').value,
        guardarPeliculaLanzamiento = document.querySelector('#lanzamiento').value;
    
    agregarDatosPelicula(guardarPeliculaTitulo, guardarPeliculaDirector, guardarPeliculaLanzamiento);
    imprimirTabla();
}

function imprimirTabla() {
    var lista = obtenerListaPelicula(),
    tbody = document.querySelector('#tablaPelicula tbody');

    tbody.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        var row = tbody.insertRow(i),
            tituloCelda = row.insertCell(0),
            directorCelda = row.insertCell(1);
            fechaCelda = row.insertCell(2);
        
        tituloCelda.innerHTML = lista[i].title;
        directorCelda.innerHTML = lista[i].director;
        fechaCelda.innerHTML = lista[i].date;

        tbody.appendChild(row);
    }
}
```

Aqui nos interesa obtener los datos que tienen los inputs a la hora de darle submit, es por ello que obtenemos el id del boton y todo eso sera guardado en una funcion llamada `guardarDatosPeliculas()` Que no es mas que una llamada a todos los inputs (con su respectivos id), estos los guardaras en la funcion `agregarDatosPeliculas()` (ya que tenemos acceso al objeto nuevaPelicula y sus datos).

Por ultimo nos queda imprimir todo esto en un tabla (para este ejemplo lo tome en cuenta). y con ello, mostrar los datos que obtienes de los inputs.

Creando una variable lista la cual obtiene la lista de las peliculas y las retorna.
tambien declaramos en donde se van a mostrar, en este caso tbody y su respectivo id. Se limpia los datos que haya en `<body></body>` con innerHTML.

Crearemos un ciclo for que mientras el tamaño de la lista sea menor a i
nuestra variable row estara insertando en tbody datos que tienes en tu archivo json.

en este caso, tenemos 3: `titulo, director y Lanzamiento`  las cuales con el metodo `insertCell()` le iremos diciendo en que posiciones se deben agregar. por ultimo, con innerHTML limpiamos e insertamos con `lista[i].propiedad...`

recuerda que en var `NuevaPelicula` le pusimos la propiedad, y este ejemplo en concreto tiene 3. `title, director y date`

```
var NuevaPelicula = {
        title: peliculaTitulo,
        director: peliculaDirector,
        date: peliculaFechaLanzamiento
    };
```

Espero haberme explicado bien, si tienes alguna duda, con gusto te contesto.

**EDIT1:**

Si deseas agregar mas datos, debes modificar tu form agregando el campo que deseas, en interfaz.js agregar otro dato en `agregarDatosPelicula(... varN)`
y tambien en `NuevaPelicula`

por ultimo, agregarlos en `guardarDatosPelicula()` con su respectivo id e imprimirlo para que se pueda visualizar en tu html

Comment: Creo que faltó la opción de guardar los datos en un archivo JSON, pero el AP no especificó si pretende guardar directamente con javascript (Mission: Impossible) o en servidor, ni lenguaje usado de ser el caso.